# MySQL error 1064 in update statement

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql> Update table product_tb set quantity=90 where pid=2;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table
 product_tb set quantity=90 where pid=2' at line 1

Comment: remove the 'table' word

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `table` keyword from the query, because it is not required here.

Try this::

```
Update product_tb set quantity=90 where pid=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table product_tb set quantity=90 where pid=2;
```

to

```
Update product_tb set quantity=90 where pid=2;
```